# Weka Java API - Euclidean Distance: Normalized vs NonNormalized

Tags: java, normalization, weka, euclidean-distance

i want to calculate the normalized euclidean distance between two vectors with length of 5. The simpler way with Apache Math and RealVector does not normalize the distance so I try to use Weka. I have followed java code:

```
Attribute one = new Attribute("one");
Attribute two = new Attribute("two");
Attribute three = new Attribute("three");
Attribute four = new Attribute("four");
Attribute five = new Attribute("five");

FastVector attributes = new FastVector();
attributes.addElement(one);
attributes.addElement(two);
attributes.addElement(three);
attributes.addElement(four);
attributes.addElement(five);

Instances wVector = new Instances("Vector", attributes, 0);

Instance firstInstance = new Instance(attributes.size());
firstInstance.setDataset(wClassVector);
firstInstance.setValue(one, 1.0);
firstInstance.setValue(two, 2.0);
firstInstance.setValue(three, 3.0);
firstInstance.setValue(four, 4.0);
firstInstance.setValue(five, 5.0);

Instance secondInstance = new Instance(attributes.size());
secondInstance.setDataset(wClassVector);
secondInstance.setValue(one, 10.0);
secondInstance.setValue(two, 20.0);
secondInstance.setValue(three, 30.0);
secondInstance.setValue(four, 40.0);
secondInstance.setValue(five, 50.0);

EuclideanDistance ed = new EuclideanDistance(wClassVector);

Double wDist = ed.distance(firstInstance, secondInstance);

ed.setDontNormalize(true);
Double wDist1 = ed.distance(firstInstance, secondInstance);
```

Why it calculates not normalized distance `wDist1` correct ether normalized distance `wDist` get `NaN` as result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normalization of the distance is based on the *ranges* of the attribute values of the instances of the data set that the distance function was created with.

Your `wVector` data set does not contain any instances. You have to add the instances like this:

```
    wVector.add(firstInstance);
    wVector.add(secondInstance);
```

Then it should work as expected.